# Вылетает ошибка при умножении двух матриц

Tags: c++, ооп, матрицы

Пытался написать программу, умножающую две матрицы. Но вылетает ошибка, после чего программа завершается. Скрин и код прилагаются. Заранее благодарю!

```
main.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include "classes.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    {
        Matrix obj1, obj2;
        cout << "Matrix 1: " << obj1 << "\nMatrix 2: " << obj2 << endl;
        Matrix result(obj1 * obj2);
        cout << "Resulting matrix: " << result << "\nYay!\n`";
        obj2 = result;
        cout << "After obj2 = result: " << obj2 << "That's it. Bye!\n";
    }
    return 0;
}

////////////////////

methods.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include "classes.h"

Matrix::Matrix()
{
    std::cout << "\nEnter the size of the matrix.\nEnter rows: ";
    std::cin >> rows;
    std::cout << "Enter columns: ";
    std::cin >> cols;
    matrix = new double* [rows];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        matrix[i] = new double[cols];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "\nRow #" << i + 1 << ":\n";
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            std::cout << "  column #" << j + 1 << ":  ";
            std::cin >> matrix[rows][cols];
        }
    }
}

Matrix::Matrix(int _rows, int _cols)
{
    rows = _rows;
    cols = _cols;
    matrix = new double* [rows];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        matrix[i] = new double[cols];
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            matrix[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

Matrix::Matrix(const Matrix& obj)
{
    rows = obj.rows;
    cols = obj.cols;
    matrix = new double* [rows];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        matrix[i] = new double[cols];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            matrix[rows][cols] = obj.matrix[rows][cols];
        }
    }
}

Matrix::~Matrix()
{
    std::cout << "\nMatrix deleted.\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        delete[] matrix[i];
    }
    delete[] matrix;
    matrix = nullptr;
}

Matrix Matrix::operator=(const Matrix& obj)
{
    if (this == &obj)
        return *this;
    this->~Matrix();
    rows = obj.rows;
    cols = obj.cols;
    matrix = new double* [rows];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        matrix[i] = new double[cols];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            matrix[rows][cols] = obj.matrix[rows][cols];
        }
    }
    return *this;
}

Matrix operator*(const Matrix& obj1, const Matrix& obj2)
{
    Matrix temp(obj1.rows, obj2.cols);
    if (obj1.cols != obj2.rows)
    {
        std:: cout << "\nThe matrix multiplication is impossible due to a rows and cols dismatch. \nPlease, enter another matrix sizes.\n\n";
        return obj1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < obj1.rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < obj2.cols; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < obj1.cols; k++)
            {
                temp.matrix[i][j] += obj1.matrix[i][k] * obj2.matrix[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
    return temp;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Matrix& obj)
{
    std::cout << "\n\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < obj.rows; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "   | ";
        for (int j = 0; j < obj.cols; j++)
        {
            std::cout << obj.matrix[i][j] << "  ";
        }
        std::cout << "\b|  \n";
    }
    return os;
}

/////////////////

classes.h

#ifndef CLASSES_H
#define CLASSES_H
#include <iostream>

class Matrix
{
private:
    double** matrix;
    int rows, cols; 
public:
    Matrix();
    Matrix(int _rows, int _cols);
    Matrix(const Matrix& obj);
    ~Matrix();
    Matrix operator=(const Matrix& obj);
    friend Matrix operator*(const Matrix& obj1, const Matrix& obj2);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Matrix& obj);
};

#endif CLASSES_H
```

[image: вывод ошибки]

Comment: Может, вы все же хотите писать **в** матрицу, а не **за** матрицей? Не `std::cin >> matrix[rows][cols];`, а `std::cin >> matrix[i][j];`? Честно - сколько минут вы пытались найти ошибку самостоятельно?

Comment: Есть несколько предположений:
нужно перед mainзадавать Matrix(void);
нужно все в одном .срр файле делать так как Visual работает в одном проекте только с одним файлом
sd::cin>>matrix[i][j];

Comment: @Harry что-же этот верный ответ должен был быть вами дан

Comment: @Harry спасибо Вам огромное, Ваш ответ помог мне исправить подобные ошибки и в других строках кода!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Должно быть `matrix[i][j]`, а не `matrix[rows][cols]`.